# VFS account is locked, tried many times. Still it is locked

Tags: vfs-global, biometric-passports

VFS account is locked, tried many times in last 5hrs. Still it is locked. I have filled the application form but cannot take appointment date due to this. Please help.

Comment: What site are you using?  What message do you get when you try to log in?  Why have you tagged the question "biometric passports"?

Comment: @user96461 I don’t mean to sound unsympathetic but we are not VFS experts. You need to contact their tech support / help desk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to the VFS tech support team

Answer (score 2):

We cannot help with this.  The only people who can help are the VFS site administrators.  Look for a link at the bottom of the page for *Contact.*